# Facing issues with libfdk-aac1 for Openbroadcaster installation on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install `Openbroadcaster` software on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and the installing is failing because of `libfdk-aac1` dependency.

Terminal Logs:

```
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done <br>
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done <br>
Some packages could not be installed. <br>This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming. <br>
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: <br>
 obs-studio : Depends: libfdk-aac1 (>= 0.1.4) but it is not installable
<br>E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of downloading and installing deb file directly in ubuntu, you should use multiverse when it is available in multiverse. libfdk-aac1 is available in multiverse. all you need to do is enable that repo.

Go to software and updates --> make sure multiverse is selected.

in console

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install libfdk-aac1
```

OR you can directly install obs-studio

```
sudo apt install obs-studio
```

and it will fetch all necessary packages.

Comment: I needed to run `sudo apt-get clean` after enabling multiverse for this to work, but after that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by:

1) Downloading the libfdk-aac1_0.1.4-2+b1_amd64.deb package directly from debian here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libfdk-aac1/download

2) Installing with:

```
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.4-2+b1_amd64.deb
```

After that I continued with the install and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: sudo apt remove obs-studio

Step 2: Download and install (copy URL and paste into the browser and hit enter)

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb

Step 3: sudo apt install obs-studio

Answer (score 0):

libfdk-aac1 (>= 0.1.5) download

```
wget https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb
```

And install

```
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb
```

source: [ubuntu packages archive](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-multiverse-amd64/libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb.html)